# How do I fit a non-linear regression to only one factor level on my scatter plot?

Tags: r, data-visualization

My data is structured like so:

'data.frame':   50 obs. of  3 variables:

- Project : Factor w/ 2 levels "A","B": 1 1 1 1 1
- x: int  2 2 2 2 6 4 4 4 6 4 ...
- y: num  0.622 0.425 0.363 0.344 0.346 ...

I have 'attached' the data and plotted both levels in my scatter plot using:

```
plot(x,y,pch=as.numeric(Project))
TSF<-x[order(x)]
SD<-y[order(x)]
```

And fitted a non-linear regression to the data

```
nls_fit <- nls(SD ~ a - (b*TSF)+ ((c*TSF)^(2)), start = list(a = 0.34, b = 0.017, 
+     c = 0.0003))
lines(TSF, predict(nls_fit), col = "red")
```

This works well...

But how can I fit this equation to only the factor "A" of the data? I'm very new at this so if you have the time an inclination it would be great if you could describe what any code you write does.

Thanks
Kris

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood correctly, there's no need to use non-linear regression for this. You can use linear regression because the model can be written in a way that the parameters appear linearly. If $E$ denotes expected value, your model is
$E(SD) = a - b \text{TSF} + c^2 \text{TSF}^2$, which you could write as $E(SD) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{TSF} + \beta_2 \text{TSF}^2$, with $\beta_0=a, \ \beta_1=-b, \ \beta_2 = c^2$.

If the name of your data frame is `d`, you can fit the model to the full data set using `lm.all <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = d)`. You can fit the model just using the "A" points using `lm.A <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2), data = subset(d, Project == "A"))`. Note that the intercept is included by default, and the `I` means that you want `x^2` to be interpreted as "x squared". Also note that there's no need to sort the data.

Comment: +1 But please note that `subset` should only be used in the global environment. See also the warning in the help file.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for the comment. I didn't know that.

Comment: Thank you Mark, that is really clear and works well. I wish I had sought help sooner!